# How to add space before and after CDATA in XML file

Tags: python, xml, lxml, cdata

I want to create a function to modify XML content without changing the format. I managed to change the text but I can't do it without changing the format in XML.
So now, what I wanted to do is to add space before and after CDATA in a XML file.

Default XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Mapsxmlns="http://www.semi.org">
  <Map>
    <Device>
      <ReferenceDevice/>
      <Bin>
        <Bin Bin="001"/>
      </Bin>
      <Data>
        <Row> <![CDATA[001 001 001]]> </Row>
      </Data>
    </Device>
  </Map>
</Maps>
```

And I am getting this result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Mapsxmlns="http://www.semi.org">
  <Map>
    <Device>
      <ReferenceDevice/>
      <Bin>
        <Bin Bin="001"/>
      </Bin>
      <Data>
        <Row><![CDATA[001 001 099]]></Row>
      </Data>
    </Device>
  </Map>
</Maps>
```

However, I want the new xml to be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Mapsxmlns="http://www.semi.org">
  <Map>
    <Device>
      <ReferenceDevice/>
      <Bin>
        <Bin Bin="001"/>
      </Bin>
      <Data>
        <Row> <![CDATA[001 001 099]]> </Row>
      </Data>
    </Device>
  </Map>
</Maps>
```

Here is my code:

```
from lxml import etree as ET

def xml_new(f,fpath,newtext,xmlrow):
    xmlrow = 19
    parser = ET.XMLParser(strip_cdata=False)
    tree = ET.parse(f, parser)
    root = tree.getroot()
    for child in root:
       value = child[0][2][xmlrow].text

    text = ET.CDATA("001 001 099")
    child[0][2][xmlrow] = ET.Element('Row')
    child[0][2][xmlrow].text = text
    child[0][2][xmlrow].tail = "\n"
    ET.register_namespace('A', "http://www.semi.org")
    tree.write(fpath,encoding='utf-8',xml_declaration=True)
    return value
```

Anyone can help me on this? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for all your help. I have found another way to achieve the result I want

This is the code:

```
# what you want to change
replaceby = '020]]> </Row>\n'
# row you want to change
row = 1
# col you want to change based on list
col = 3
file = open(file,'r')
line = file.readlines()
i = 0
editedXML=[]
for l in line:
    if 'cdata' in l.lower():
        i=i+1
        if i == row:
            oldVal = l.split(' ')
            newVal = []
            for index, old in enumerate(oldVal):
                if index == col:
                    newVal.append(replaceby)
                else:
                    newVal.append(old)
            editedXML.append(' '.join(newVal))
        else:
            editedXML.append(l)
    else:
        editedXML.append(l)
file2 = open(newfile,'w')
file2.write(''.join(editedXML))
file2.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand what you want to do. Here's an example for you. I don't know if it can meet your needs.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc,req,utils
html ='''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Mapsxmlns="http://www.semi.org">
  <Map>
    <Device>
      <ReferenceDevice/>
      <Bin>
        <Bin Bin="001"/>
      </Bin>
      <Data>
        <Row> <![CDATA[001 001 001]]> </Row>
      </Data>
    </Device>
  </Map>
</Maps>'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
row = doc.Data.Row # Get the node you want to modify.
row.setContent(" "+row.html+" ") # Modify the node content.
print (doc.html)
```

Result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Mapsxmlns="http://www.semi.org">
  <Map>
    <Device>
      <ReferenceDevice />
      <Bin>
        <Bin Bin="001" />
      </Bin>
      <Data>
        <Row>  <![CDATA[001 001 001]]>  </Row>
      </Data>
    </Device>
  </Map>
</Maps>
```